# Android 2.2 post Highscore to google play service

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-2.2-froyo

i am using a leaderboard via gps google play service. This is the only think i am using from the gps library at the moment.
For users with a Android Version 2.2 aka Froyo this does not work.
Is there a way to post the highscore to the leaderboard on a device which runs Android 2.2?
For other devices, it works fine.

This is my code:

```
public void showHighscore() {
    Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mHelper_.getApiClient(),
            getString(R.string.leaderboard_highscore), this.getIntent()
                    .getExtras().getInt("highscore"));

    int REQUEST_LEADERBOARD = 1;// beliebiger int
    startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(
            mHelper_.getApiClient(),
            getString(R.string.leaderboard_highscore)), REQUEST_LEADERBOARD);
}
```

Comment: Is there a crash or an error in the log?

Comment: I posted a long answer here..

http://stackoverflow.com/a/24214612/3733450

Comment: The Link has nothing to do with Android 2.2 as it is clearly stated in the question.

Answer (score 1):

As of [Google Play Services 4.0](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/google-play-services-40.html), the minimum API version for Google Play Services is Android 2.3 (Gingerbread).

You can instead use the 'Google Play services for Froyo' from the SDK Manager and [reference Google Play Services version 3.2.65](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20640084/1676363) (the last available for Froyo), but obviously will not have access to any of the new APIs.

Comment: Does the Google Play services for Froyo give you acccess to the google plus leaderboard system? It is very hard to find relevant information and Documentation.

Comment: Support for Froyo has been deprecated for over 6 months now so finding documentation or examples would be very difficult. Google Play Games and leaderboards **did** come out prior to Google Play Services 4.0, so they are available for Froyo users. Do note however, that the current GoogleApiClient based model (which provides a more reliable connection experience and a new API for accessing multiple Google services) has only recently been introduced and would not be available for Froyo.